# How to store metadata with Ceph?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, filesystems, cdn, ceph

I want to store user files in CephFS. The problem is that I also need to store some metadata of these files (Download date, verification status for example), as well as the ability to sort by date or the ability to give a number. If I use Mongodb for metadata, I have synchronization problem (file can be in database but not in CephFS or vice versa)

The file structure in CephFS is as follows:
/{user.id}/{Media collection name}/{media.id}

The media.id is uuidv4.

What idea I have:
Create a "meta" folder, in which to put the metadata of the files by their id, but without the date the file was uploaded to CephFS. To access the date, use data from CephFS(It stores the date the file was created, changed, just like any other file system(?))

I didn't find information in the Ceph documentation that it stores metadata as well, so I'm not sure if this option would work.

Comment: It depends what we mean by metadata. Sounds like you want to create additional files (eg: `/{user.id}/{Media collection name}/{media.id}.meta`). CephFS own metadata are dealt by the Ceph MDS component, though I would assume that's not what you meant?

Comment: @SYN, I want to store data there that would otherwise be in the database. The problem is that if you store them in the database, there will be problems with synchronization when restoring from backups, so it is better to store both files and additional data together.

I was also thinking of just making an extra file with metadata separately. Should I answer my question this way?